# What is the "-s" in "npm run -s build"

Tags: npm

What's the purpose of an `"-s"` flag in `"npm run -s build"`? I've searched in npm docs, but can't find, Is this an alias for `"--silent"` flag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to:
https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/5e426a78ca02d0044f8dd26e0c5f881217081cbd/doc/misc/npm-config.md

```
Shorthands and Other CLI Niceties
-s, --silent: --loglevel silent
```